# rotate on hammer.js bug

Tags: rotation, hammer.js

I have an issue with rotate on hammer.js. On first touch with two fingers the element immediately rotates through 180 deg. Even the rotate example at http://hammerjs.github.io/ does this strange behaviour. Any bug fix?

Comment: I have the same issue. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

You can fix this by working with differential rotation instead of actual rotation value.

Find more at this [issue](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/914)

```js
// get a reference to an element
var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
$stage = jQuery(stage);

// create a manager for that element
var manager = new Hammer.Manager(stage);

// create recognizers
var Pan = new Hammer.Pan();
var Rotate = new Hammer.Rotate();
var Pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
var Tap = new Hammer.Tap({
  taps: 1
});
var DoubleTap = new Hammer.Tap({
  event: 'doubletap',
  taps: 2
});

// use them together
Rotate.recognizeWith([Pan]);
Pinch.recognizeWith([Rotate, Pan]);

DoubleTap.recognizeWith([Tap]);
Tap.requireFailure([DoubleTap]);

// add the recognizers
manager.add(Pan);
manager.add(Rotate);
manager.add(Pinch);
manager.add(DoubleTap);
manager.add(Tap);

// subscribe to events
var liveScale = 1;
var currentRotation = 0, lastRotation, startRotation;
manager.on('rotatemove', function(e) {
    // do something cool
    var diff = startRotation - Math.round(e.rotation);
  currentRotation = lastRotation - diff;
    $.Velocity.hook($stage, 'rotateZ', currentRotation + 'deg');
});
manager.on('rotatestart', function(e) {
  lastRotation = currentRotation;
  startRotation = Math.round(e.rotation);
});
manager.on('rotateend', function(e) {
    // cache the rotation
    lastRotation = currentRotation;
});

var deltaX = 0;
var deltaY = 0;
manager.on('panmove', function(e) {
  // do something cool
  var dX = deltaX + (e.deltaX);
  var dY = deltaY + (e.deltaY);
  $.Velocity.hook($stage, 'translateX', dX + 'px');
  $.Velocity.hook($stage, 'translateY', dY + 'px');
});
manager.on('panend', function(e) {
  deltaX = deltaX + e.deltaX;
  deltaY = deltaY + e.deltaY;
});

// subscribe to events
var currentScale = 1;
function getRelativeScale(scale) {
  return scale * currentScale;
}
manager.on('pinchmove', function(e) {
  // do something cool
  var scale = getRelativeScale(e.scale);
  $.Velocity.hook($stage, 'scale', scale);
});
manager.on('pinchend', function(e) {
  // cache the scale
  currentScale = getRelativeScale(e.scale);
  liveScale = currentScale;
});

var colors = [
  [20, 187, 95],
  [20, 95, 187],
  [187, 95, 20],
  [187, 20, 95],
  [95, 20, 187],
  [95, 187, 20]
];
function mult(a, b) {
  return Math.round(a * b);
}
function makeColor(rgb, adj) {
  adj = adj || 1;
  return 'rgb('+mult(rgb[0], adj)+','+mult(rgb[1], adj)+','+ mult(rgb[2], adj)+')';
}
var currentColorIndex = 0;
manager.on('tap', function(e) {
  currentColorIndex++;
  if (currentColorIndex >= colors.length) {
    currentColorIndex = 0;
  }
  stage.style.backgroundColor = makeColor(colors[currentColorIndex]);
  stage.style.borderColor = makeColor(colors[currentColorIndex], 0.85);
});

var isShrunken = false;
manager.on('doubletap', function() {
  console.log('doubletapped');
  var scale = $.Velocity.hook($stage, 'scale');
  if (isShrunken) {
    $.Velocity.hook($stage, 'scale', 2 * scale);
  } else {
    $.Velocity.hook($stage, 'scale', .5 * scale);
  }
  isShrunken = !isShrunken;
});
```

```css
#stage {
  background: #20bb5f;
  border: 5px solid #009b2f;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 30px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hammerjs/touchemulator/master/touch-emulator.js"></script>
<script> TouchEmulator(); </script>
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js"></script>

<div id="stage"><span>Stage</span></div>
```

Comment: Works on Windows-Firefox version 54.0.1 (32 bits). Does not work on Windows-Chrome version 59.0.3071.115 official build (64 bits).